# Matching Delimiters With Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I have a situation where I need to validate social security numbers, and they can be input in any of the three following formats:

123-45-6789
123/45/6789
123456789

I tried writing a regular expression to match these, and came up with this:

```
^[0-9]{3}(-|/)?[0-9]{2}(-|/)?[0-9]{4}$
```

which is close, but it still allows strings like `123-45/6789` through, which I would like to prevent. Is there any way to match the delimiters such that all hypens are allowed, and all forward slashes are allowed, but not a combination of the two?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
^[0-9]{3}([-|/]?)[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{4}$
```

The `\1` is a backreference to the subpattern `([-|/]?)`, so it matches whatever was found for the first delimiter.

Comment: It will match `123-456789` not sure if it is desired or not.

Comment: You're right. I edited the pattern to fix this, so it shouldn't match 123-456789 now.

Comment: Not quite right because now it will start matching `123|45|6789` as well.

Comment: `[-|/]` matches on of `'-'`, `'|'` and `'/'`. Yes, it matches a `'|'` as well (try it).

Comment: Darn, you're right! OK, I'm upvoting your answer. Thanks for the education.

Answer (score 4):

Better to use this regex:

```
/^\d{3}(\/|-|)\d{2}\1\d{4}$/
```

This will not match `123-45/6789` and `123-456789` but
will match `123-45-6789` or `123/45/6789` or `123456789`

Comment: @BartKiers: Thanks so much for escaping `/` in my answer, I was actually testing it in PHP using pattern `#^\d{3}(/|-|)\d{2}\1\d{4}$#` but while posting I thought better to not to use `#` since OP hadn't mentioned the platform of the regex and left inner `/` un-escaped.

Comment: :) the funny thing was that I saw the un-escaped `/` because the syntax highlighter of SO displayed the characters after the un-escaped `/` in a different color.

Comment: True, I should have paid close attention to the color highlighter of SO :)

Comment: +1 But I would use `([\-/]?)` instead of `(\/|-|)`. (Slightly more efficient.)